# CSS conditional setting when selector is true

Tags: css, sass, styles

So I've come up trumps on this one; saying that, SCSS and CSS are not my strong points. To give context on my issue, we have a small issue on one of our screens that we need a quick fix for until more work is done to alleviate a shortcoming of what's already been done.

To give you context we removed an attribute overflow-y: auto from the class SideNavContainer__content as nothing else other than this one component seems to have issues with it. And for now I'm in a position that for this specific component I need an override rot add it back to restore the functionality for now.

```
div.SideNavContainer__content {
  padding: 1rem;
  margin: -1rem -1rem -1rem 0;
  z-index: 0;

  & div.Content_component > div.PriceProfileLanding {
    overflow-y: auto;
  }
}
```

As you can see here the is the selector down to the effected html but what I need to do is essentially add the overflow-y: auto; to the parent when this selector is found in the DOM, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

So after alot of digging it doesn't look like css has a way of achieving this so for now I just used js to attach in the component that requires the modification